# why can't I create a Git branch from master?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I cloned a repo and VScode shows that it's `master`.  I want to create a branch, but I get this:

`GIT: fatal: ‘HEAD’ is not a commit and a branch branch name cannot be created from it`

I checked git log and its says:

```
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

this is my first time using get, please advise

Comment: Just create an initial commit or maybe use `--orphan`.

Comment: ahh thank you!! the initial commit did the trick

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't yet created a single revision on the repository, you can switch to a different branch from master/main by running:

```
git branch -m a-new-name
```

Comment: You'd "loose" the `main` branch though. This might be confusing as it would need to be (re)created later.

Comment: Ok... but it would lose something that does not exist at the moment.

Comment: Sure but just adding the info as it might not be obvious to people new to Git and used to always have a `main` branch.

Comment: I guess your comments will do for the time being XD. Let me upvote them, just in case.

Comment: You can't (at least in many versions of Git) rename an orphan branch with `git branch -m` (I haven't checked the latest Git yet); you have to use `git checkout --orphan` or `git checkout -b` instead (both work). This seems like a bug to me, so if it's fixed in the current Git, that's probably good... :-)

Comment: Well... coming from an orphan branch, I wouldn't know. But on a brand new repo, when you haven't committed for the first time, it does work to run `git branch -m main`, for example (I have tried it myself): `git init temp; cd temp; git branch -m main`.

Comment: `$ git init` [Initialized empty Git repository in ...]  `$ git branch -m asdf` produces: `error: refname refs/heads/master not found` and `fatal: Branch rename failed` (in Git 2.27.0, which is not the latest).

Comment: 2.30.0 over here. Wanna go for some bisect-hunting? :-D

Comment: It's commit [cfaff3aac8063ec72f03c6761328c7fa44a15b34](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfaff3aac8063ec72f03c6761328c7fa44a15b34), first released as part of 2.30.0.

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it let me make a new branch:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Empty initial commit'
```

EDIT: this creates an empty commit as 1 first commit is needed before creating a branch from the current branch.

Answer (score 1):

You have already answered this yourself, as have several others, but there is a deeper point here that's worth mentioning.  The reason `git branch` fails here is simple enough: **A branch name, in Git, contains the raw hash ID of the *last* commit that is to be considered a member of the branch.**  This might not seem weird or startling, at least to someone new to Git and version control, but it in fact *is* weird and startling, to someone who is not new to version control, but *is* new to Git.  **Most version control systems that *aren't* Git *don't work this way:* in most version control systems, commits made on branch *B* are now part of branch *B* forever.  But in Git, the set of branches that contain any one given commit—which may be many or all branches—*changes* over time!**

The way to understand this visually, at least, is to draw a series of commits and some branch names:

```
A  <-B  <-C   <--main
```

Here, we have a small starting repository with just three commits in it.  Real commits have big, ugly, unique, random-looking *hash IDs*, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), such as [<sup><sub>75ae10bc75336db031ee58d13c5037b929235912</sub></sup>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75ae10bc75336db031ee58d13c5037b929235912), that are too difficult for humans to bother with, so I've used uppercase letters to stand in for them.  The *branch name* `main` here contains the raw hash ID of the *last* of these commits.  We say that the name *points to* the commit.

The commit itself contains two things:

- It has a complete snapshot of all of the files, as of the time you (or whoever) made it, stored in a special internal Git-only format in which the files are compressed and de-duplicated.  The de-duplication takes care of the fact that every commit stores a full copy of every file: since most commits mostly just re-use older commits' files, they wind up taking no space.<sup>1</sup>
- It has some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes the name and email address of whoever *made* the commit, and some date-and-time-stamps.

In the metadata for commit `C`, Git has stored the raw hash ID of earlier commit `B`.  So just as `main` points to `C`, we say that `C` points to `B`.  This means that Git can use the name `main` to find `C`, then use `C` to find `B`.

Commit `B`, of course, is also a commit, so it has a full snapshot and metadata.  The metadata inside commit `B` includes the hash ID of earlier commit `A`, so `B` points to `A`.

The process of adding a new commit to a branch consists of:

- writing out the contents of the commit—the snapshot and the metadata—which gives the new commit its new, unique, big ugly hash ID;
- storing the raw hash ID of the *new* commit into the *branch name*.

The new commit's backwards-looking pointer, of course, must point to whatever commit *was* the last commit before.  Now new commit `D` is the last commit, and the chain goes:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main
```

No part of any commit—neither its data, nor its metadata—can be changed once you *make* the commit.  (This is why it's safe for commits to *share* one copy of a file, for instance.)  So this means the links between commits are *necessarily* backwards: we never know, in advance, what the raw hash ID of some *future* commit will be, because it depends in part on the *exact second* we will (in the future) make that commit.  It's impossible to predict, so a commit never points forwards, to its children: it only points backwards, to its parents.  (This means we can be lazy and not draw the arrows between commits using arrows, if we don't have good drawing characters for instance.  We just remember that they must necessarily point backwards.)

This is how and why Git commits are on more than one branch.  Let's start with a repository with eight commits in it:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- main
```

Now let's create a *new* branch, such as `feature`, that *also selects commit `H`*, like this:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- main, feature
```

Now—without worrying about *how* we do it—we create two new commits on `main`, then two new commits on `feature`:

```
          I--J   <-- main
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- feature
```

Note that commits up through and including `H` are on *both branches*; commits `I-J` are, at the moment, only on `main`, and commits `K-L` are only on `feature`.

If we now run:

```
git checkout main
git merge feature
```

and the merge is successful, we end up with a series of commits that look like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- main
         \    /
          K--L   <-- feature
```

The new *merge commit* `M` is special in exactly one way: it has *two* parents, pointing back to both `J` *and* `L`.  Suddenly, commits `K-L` are now on branch `main`, as well as still being on branch `feature`.  Commits `I-J` are still *only* on `main`, and commits through `H` are still on both branches, but `main` has acquired three commits, even though we only created one commit.

Note that merge commit `M` still has one snapshot of all files, and the usual author and committer and log message in its metadata.  The only thing special about it is that it has these two parents, instead of the usual one.  That's what makes it a *merge commit*.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>These de-duplicated files do take a *tiny* bit of space, to hold the information that the file is present, but not enough to worry about.  The file contents themselves are stored separately as *blob objects*, which get their own hash IDs.  Git also has tricks that it employs later to make *nearly*-duplicate files smaller, via something it calls *pack files*, but you don't have to worry about that: it's almost completely invisible.

<sup>2</sup>Note that `git merge` does not always make a merge commit, and other commands—such as `git cherry-pick`—use Git's merge *code* internally, but make a *non-merge* commit.  The upshot of this is that *to merge*, as a verb, means something very different from *a merge*, as a noun.  We use `git merge` to make merges, but the whole picture around merging is, um, let's just say *nontrivial*.   This is why a good Git book will spend at least a whole chapter on merging.

---

#### Back to that first-commit problem

Once you've digested the above—at least to the point of being able to draw some simple branch examples—it's time to try to draw a branch that has *no* commits on it.

We *can* do this, sort of, on paper or on a whiteboard:

```
      <-- main
```

but if we do that, Git is supposed to be able to answer the question: *what is the hash ID that goes with this branch name?*  So, what *is* the hash ID?

I don't know, and neither do you: it doesn't exist yet.  There *will be one* in the future, probably, but we don't know what it is.  To find out what hash ID the next commit we make has, we have to make it.

That's why your solution—of making a new but empty commit—works: once we make commit `A`, it gets assigned a hash ID, and the name `main` (or `master`) can point to it:

```
A   <-- main
```

We can make as many names as we like now.  They all just have to point to `A`, since that's the only commit:

```
A   <-- main, master, develop, topic, feature/short, feature/tall
```

But, when we first create an empty *repository*—one that has no commits in it—we're always in this weird state, where we can't have any *branch names* either.  We get out of the weird state by making the first commit.

**There's a trick here.**  When Git creates a new commit, what Git does is:

- read the hash ID from the current branch name: that's the parent hash ID;
- gather the rest of the metadata: your name, the current date-and-time, your log message, and so on;
- write out the snapshot (`git write-tree`) and the commit itself (`git commit-tree`), which generates the hash ID; and
- update the current branch name to hold the hash ID of the new commit.

When there isn't any *current commit*, as in this special situation in a new repository, there's still a *current branch name*.<sup>3</sup>  It's just that this branch doesn't exist!  Git has two names for this, calling it an *unborn branch* sometimes, and an *orphan branch* at other times.

What Git does, when you're on an unborn branch, is that it *notices*, in that first step.  It tries to read the current hash ID from the current branch name.  *This fails because the branch does not exist,* but Git does not panic: it just says *Aha, it's time to create the branch!*  Git goes ahead and creates a commit with *no parent*.  Then Git writes the hash ID of the new commit *into* the branch name, which creates the branch.

The end result is commit `A`: the one that does not point backwards, because it can't.  Git calls this kind of commit—one with no parent—a *root commit*, and modern Git prints `[root commit]` when you make one.

**You can make more than one root commit if you want,** but there's nothing special about extra root commits and they only have a few specialized uses.  So there's rarely any reason to bother.  If you *do* want to make a new root commit, the user-oriented commands for this are `git checkout --orphan` and `git switch --orphan`.  These two commands are actually different, but we'll stop here for this answer.

---

<sup>3</sup>The underlying mechanism that Git uses for this is that there is a very special name,<sup>4</sup> `HEAD`, that stores the *name of the current branch*.  This is implemented today as a file in `.git/HEAD`, and you can inspect it directly with any file viewer, but in general you should not alter it directly: use `git update-ref --symbolic` from programs, or other more user-oriented Git commands from the command-line.

<sup>4</sup>This name is so special that if the `.git/HEAD` file goes missing, Git stops believing that the repository *is* a repository.  Because the `HEAD` file is relatively active, sometimes a computer crash causes the OS to remove the `HEAD` file.  You can recover from this by creating an appropriate `.git/HEAD` file.  You should never have to do this, because your computer never crashes or bluescreens or has the power fail, right?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you cloned your own branch and follow step :
`git branch mynewBranch`